# How to set time object on SLA in airflow instead of timedelta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to implement SLA in my airflow DAG.

I know how SLAs work, you set a timedelta object and if the task does not get done in that duration, it will send an email and notifies that the task is not done yet.

I want some similar functionality, but instead of giving duration, I want to set specific time in SLA. For example, if the task is not done due to 8:00 AM, it sends the email and notifies the manager. Something like this:

```
'sla': time(hour=8, minute=0, second=0)
```

I have searched a lot, but nothing found.

Is there any solution for this specific problem? or any other solutions than SLA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SLA` param of `BaseOperator` expects a `datetime.timedelta` object, so there is nothing more to do there. Take into consideration that `SLA` represents a time delta after the scheduled period is over. The example from the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html?highlight=sla) supposes a DAG scheduled daily:

> For example if you set an SLA of 1 hour, the scheduler would send an email soon after 1:00AM on the 2016-01-02 if the 2016-01-01 instance has not succeeded yet.

The point is, it's always a time delta from the schedule period which is not what you are looking for.

So I think you should take another approach, like schedule your DAG whenever you need it, execute the tasks you want and then add a *sensor operator* to check if the condition you are looking for is met or not. There are a few types of [sensors](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-sensors/) depending on the context you have you could choose from them.

Another option could be, create a new *DAG* dedicated to check if your tasks executed in the original *DAG* were successfully executed or not, and act accordingly (for example, send emails, etc.). To do this you could use an `ExternalTaskSensor`, check online for tutorials on how to implement it, although it may be simpler to avoid cross DAG dependencies as stated in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html#cross-dag-dependencies).

Hope that this could point you into the right direction.